# Android : Split string with { character

Tags: android, string, split

I have an string

```
String name = "\"edge_followed_by\":{\"count\":46199005},\"followed_by_viewer\":false,"
```

I want only this **46199005**.

But `{` shows an error, when try to split the string

```
String[] separated = name.split("edge_followed_by\":{\"count\":");
```

Showing a suggestion , number expected and want me to replace with *.

Can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `{` with `\{`.

`split` is trying to use it as a part of regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should use JSON to parse this if you have proper structure. but if you want to get only the number you can split it using ":" and then split using "}". it should give you the exact number.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use:

```
String[] separated = name.split(":");
separated[2].split("}")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string is not exact JSON object otherwise you can simply do json parsing and get the `count` value.

You can get count value using subtring operations like below:

```
String name = "\"edge_followed_by\":{\"count\":46199005},\"followed_by_viewer\":false,";

String substr = name.substring(name.indexOf("\"count\":") + 10);

String finalstr = substr.substring( 0, substr.indexOf("},"));

Log.d("Extracted_Value", finalstr); // output -> 46199005
```

There can be multiple ways. This is just one. Hope it will help you!